# Why is the Bayes error rate positive?

Tags: machine-learning

In "An Introduction to Statistical Learning" by James, Witten, Hastie, Tibshirani on page 39 the authors explain why the Bayes error rate is greater than zero - "It is greater than zero because the classes overlap in the true population so $max_j Pr(Y=j|X=x_0)<1$ for some values of $x_0$". I don't understand this explanation. Can someone please help me understand the authors' explanation? Thank you.

Comment: Is zero not a trivial boundary? What would a negative error rate be like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to think about what they're saying - consider the two populations, groups A and B, shown below:

[image: Population distributions A and B]

Groups A and B vary along dimension X, and Group B tends to have higher values of X than Group A does. But, there are exceptions to this general rule; *some* members of Group A have higher values than *some* members of Group B.

If your classifier is trying to learn a function that uses values of X to discriminate between instances of Category A and B, it won't ever be able to do this with perfect accuracy because of this overlap.

For example, if your classifier function says "If X > 2, it's a member of group B", then you'll mistakenly place half the members of Group A into Group B"

[image: Population distributions A and B with classifier threshold]

If you imagine sweeping this classifier line back and forth along the x-axis, you'll see that you can't find an x-axis position that perfectly separates the two populations, because the population distributions overlap.